# access array items, which are values in a dict over a loop

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I work with dicts that look like this:

```
{0: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 1: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0]), 2: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0]), 3: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 4: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0]), 5: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 6: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 7: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 8: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 9: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])}
```

and I would like to access the first (second, third...) entry of each array individually over a loop. I already tried accessing the values and converting them to lists and several other loops, but couldn't make it work.

thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest possible solution is to just keep an index:

```py
for i in range(n):  # n must be the same across all arrays!
  for key, arr in dict.items():
    f(arr[i])
```

However, that is pretty inefficient on large data. If your input is large consider if you can do the operations in the same iteration of the dict-loop somehow, e.g.:

```py
sums = [0 for _ in range(n)]
for key, arr in dict.items():
  for idx, e in enumerate(arr):
    sums[idx] += e
```

It has the same number of combined iterations, but the memory access pattern is much better, because you don't have to fetch every array n times, but just once.